# JSP output encoding

Tags: jsp, character-encoding

When I write the following

```
é
```

or even

```
<%=new String(new byte[]{(byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0xA9}, "UTF-8")%>
```

I get a string with the length of 1. It contains a single UTF-8 character `C3A9` or `é`.

But when it gets written to the browser, the browser cannot decode it unless I use latin1. So that means it is getting encoded and written as western even though in the top of the JSP I have

```
<%@page import="..." contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>
```

How can I get the JSP to output UTF-8 instead of writing a UTF-8 header and then encoding with latin1? "Western (ISO-8859-1)"

Comment: Wow, what's wrong with just writing `é` or very maybe at highest `<%="é"%>` in the template?

Comment: @BalusC: I wanted to guarantee that there were no editor encoding issues. Edited.

Comment: Ah, you're using MSIE as browser?

Comment: @BalusC: No. Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use `pageEncoding`, and write the symbol itself, rather then referring to it by its code.

Also make sure your `.jsp` file is also encoded in UTF-8. Your IDE should handle the `pageEncoding` attribute and set the encoding appropriately, but with particular settings or if not using an IDE, the `.jsp` can still be encoded in `ISO-8859-1`. Change that to `UTF-8`

Finally, make sure your response is really using `UTF-8` as encoding (use firebug for example). If not, try setting it `response.setCharacterEncoding(..)`

Comment: Replaced the `<%=...%>` clause with single character `é`. I am using NetBeans IDE and have verified with a hex editor that it correctly encoded in UTF-8 and shows the two bytes `C3A9` on the left and the character `é` on the right. Still it does not work. I even checked the generated ..._jsp.java file. It correctly shows the same character and same encoding. So the problem can only be in either the .java to .class compile time or the encoding at runtime.

Comment: @George Bailey well, it works for me. Try my last suggestion. If it doesn't work, there's something more in your case that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Thus you were already writing to the response before you called `@page pageEncoding`? Otherwise this shouldn't happen and this is actually also not the correct solution for in a JSP. The `@page` should be the firstmost line in the JSP and the preprocessing servlet -if any- shouldn't have written any character to the response body.

Comment: @BalusC: I think the problem was that I was using `include` instead of `forward` in order to call the JSP. I have not been using `forward` because it changes the URL to the path to the JSP which is never what I am after.

Comment: the `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` has to be set in **ALL** JSPs, thus also in the parent JSP and not only in the child JSP.

Comment: @Goerge Bailey @BalusC is right - my suggestion was only to verify where the problem lies. Now you have to find why it didn't work. includes shouldn't count, unless they are placed _above_ the page declaration. Put it on top.

Comment: @BalusC: Do you mean all `.jsp`s and all `.jspf`s? I am already setting it in all `.jsp`s. And I am not calling include from a JSP but from a servlet.

Comment: @Bozho: The page `<%@page` declaration is the very first thing (character 0 on the first line) in my JSP. And the include statement is in a servlet. Not in a JSP.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks a lot! your comment was exactly what I needed, the application I'm working on was using the `pageEncoding` in an include so was not working as expected